# Extract text from pdf file using jsr223 preprocessor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jsr223

How to extract the text/content of a pdf file using JSR223 PreProcessor in JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a library like [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) for this

1. Add it and all its [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jars up
3. The simplest code to read text from PDF would be something like:

   ```
   def doc = org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(new File('path-to-the-file.pdf'))
   def text = new org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper().getText(doc)

   //now do what you need with the text, i.e. save it into ${text} JMeter variable

   vars.put('text', text)
   ```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)
- [Apache PDFBox Cookbook - Text Extraction](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/textextraction.html)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri thanks for your answer . but when I have run the above snippet code it gives an error like " javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script7.groovy: 3: Unexpected input: 'text' @ line 3, column 5.
   def text = new org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper().getText(doc)
       ^
"   can you please tell me what I am missing here ??

Comment: You (actually I) were missing closing parentheses `)` in the first line, apologies for the typo